# Angular-ui-select need to implement different behaviour on clear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-select

My use case is that the models I connect angular-ui-select too need to allow a null option, even after a user has selected one he needs to return to null if desired.

I've used the `allow-clear` attribute but it doesn't have the behaviour I expected to, see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G3f7ox2suhUNM8e86jOb?p=preview)

So what I need is not for the mission field to be deleted but for it's value to be set to null.

Comment: Works pretty good for me, little cross is showing  at the right side of select box, after clicking it - box is emptied.

Comment: @Andrey true but if you use a more complex model like in the plunker the field is deleted on a clear and that's what I want to change instead of deleting I want to set the field to null

Comment: in real, this field is not deleted, it becomes `undefined`. It doesn't printed, because undefined doesn't printed. But it still presented in object. If you need `null`, you can use `$scope.$watch` on `mission` and every time it gets undefined - set it to `null`